# Creating a BUS topology using graphviz in VScode

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I am new to graphviz. I would like to draw a diagram like this

[image]

However, this is what i'm getting. with the following code

[image]

```
  graph BUS_TOPOLOGY{
      workstation1[shape=box pos = "100,50!"];
      workstation2[shape=box];
      workstation3[shape=box];
      workstation4[shape=box];
      workstation5[shape=box];
      workstation6[shape=box];

      bus[shape=rectangle width=15]

      workstation1 -- bus --workstation4
      workstation2 -- bus --workstation5
      workstation3 -- bus --workstation6

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request pushes the envelope, but is "doable".  While you want vertical edges connecting the nodes to the bus, **dot** has no such directive.  I have no knowledge of VScode, but here is a (partial) solution in straight **dot**.  It uses an **html-record** to create explicit ports on the bus:

```
digraph structs {
  node [shape=rectangle]
  {
      rank=same
      ws1 ws2 ws3
  }
    node [shape=plaintext]
    bus [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="1" CELLBORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0" >
<TR>
<TD WIDTH="46" HEIGHT="12" PORT="p1"></TD>
<TD WIDTH="46" HEIGHT="12" PORT="p2"></TD>
<TD WIDTH="46" HEIGHT="12" PORT="p3"></TD>
<TD WIDTH="46" HEIGHT="12" PORT="p4"></TD>
<TD WIDTH="46" HEIGHT="12" PORT="p5"></TD>
<TD WIDTH="46" HEIGHT="12" PORT="p6"></TD>
<TD WIDTH="46" HEIGHT="12" PORT="p7"></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>>];

  node [shape=rectangle]
  {
      rank=same
      ws4 ws5 ws6
  }
  edge [dir=none]
  ws1 -> bus:p1;
  bus:p2 -> ws4
  ws2 -> bus:p3;
  bus:p4 -> ws5
  ws3 -> bus:p5;
  bus:p6 -> ws6
}
```

Result:
[image]